# Checking google zone usage per regions?

Tags: virtual-machines, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine

I have been having issues since the last few days starting a middle size VM on google cloud with an error telling me the zones downs have enough resources, and to try another one.

Before I try moving it to another zone I would like to make sure the other zone as resources available. Is there such a thing, as I would like to know which zone would be more appropriate instead of going to a random one an repeating the process until it works

Comment: Which *specific* type of instance were you trying to launch? https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types

Comment: it is a simple 8 cores 150gig linux instance, n1-standard-8

Comment: Check your quotas? https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas

Answer (score 1):

If you are receiving the following "ERROR: ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED: The zone 'projects/xxxxxx-project/zones/xxxxxx' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later.

This means that there's not enough resources to fulfill your request which is always temporary, could be for hours, days or weeks.

Workaround would be to probably move the workload to other zones (b/c/f) within the region or try again later as many instances are created and deleted in seconds.

Google also monitor zone utilization and add new resources as demand increases. You may also check your quota, to ensure that you have enough quota to handle the request.

Comment: Thank I am going to check our company quota, but what I dont get is, if there is limitation like that one would expect a interface to checkout where there is resource and low latency so I could move my VM to the appropriate zone, not just guessing

Comment: A system for monitoring zone/religion resource availability in real-time would be really awesome as it will help with capacity planning. You may submit a feature request. https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#search_for_or_create_bugs_and_feature_requests_by_product